# How to pipe output of a node CLI program to shell?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I basically want to do something like this:

```
$ my-node-cli <some-param> | less
```

Note that `less` is just an example. I need it to work with any other *nix command.

More about the use case:
I wrote a node CLI package that searches some online resource and outputs results to the shell. Since the result set can be huge, client wants to do additional operations on it, e.g `grep`, `head`, `tail`, `tee`, ... anything really.

I searched far and wide and I only managed to find the way to pipe *into* node program, not *out of*. My current idea is to capture the right side of pipe when my program is called, then, after I obtain results, execute my results concatenated with pipe (and that part I remembered when I was called) using `child_process.exec`. Not sure whether that could work though?

Note that each time my program is called it's a new process, i.e. the program doesn't have it's own prompt.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, it "*outputs results to the shell*"? You mean it simply writes to `stdout`? Then why wouldn't that pipe work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is output from STDOUT in your application.  This will be sent to the next program if piped to it.

You can use plain old `console.log()` or the [`process.stdout` stream](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout).

It's up to the shell to handle stream redirection, not your application.

Comment: Right, that was silly of me, that's why there are no resources on the web, it's so straightforward. Thanks guys, I had a bug which led me to believe that the pipe is what's causing it, when it was something inside my own code.